# Adding and external platform library to AOSP

Tags: android-source, gpio

I'm trying to add an external library to my AOSP (v9.0.0-2.0.0) image by following the instructions provided with said library. The instructions are:

```
cd <aosp source folder>/external/libgpiod
    mm
```

Then I run `luch` and then `make` to build the image then I flashed it to the SD card. But when I the library commands it via adb shell, none of them work. I get the response:

```
dart_mx8mm:/system/app # gpiodetect 0
/system/bin/sh: gpiodetect: not found
```

Although I can see that there are some files name the same as the library in the `/out` folder.

Is there any way to debug this? The log file isn't helping me very much.

The library in question is https://github.com/technexion-android/platform_external_libgpiod

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please specify the problem you are encountering when running the commands via adb.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I edited my question accordingly. I hope that clarifies the subject.

Comment: Did you rebuild the system image after running `mm`?

Comment: Sorry, I see now you wrote you ran `make` afterwards. Can you check if the file corresponding to the library occur in `out/.../system` (e.g. `out/.../system/bin`) or a different sub-folder of `out`?

Comment: Ok one more thing, did you run `lunch` before `mm`? I'm wondering how `mm` would know for which target to build otherwise.

Comment: I can't find any files related to this library in `out/../system/bin`, ran `mm` then `lunch`, but I have always run `lunch` for the same target.

Comment: Run `find out -name "*gpiod*"` and show the output.